# Customize title bar in Lwuit to look like J2ME default Status bar

Tags: java-me, lwuit, statusbar, menubar

I want to show the status bar in My J2ME application and I am using Lwuit too. I could not find a way to do that Especially that I m also having problems with the default menu in Lwuit. So  I want to customize the title bar in Lwuit to look like the status bar which show the notifications and the time in J2ME.

Any idea/help or from where should i start?

Comment: @khan: please do not format non-code as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should need to google it first as LWUIT blogs are now eaisly available every where. Please see [this blog](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2010_04_01_archive.html) for your purpose it will surely help you.[Here is another blog](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2008/07/pimp-my-lwuit-part-1-gradient-galore.html) you should see so you can get start for `titleBar` and its customization.
I hope these links will surely help you

Comment: Thank you, i already saw these links, they are talking about customizing the title bar by adding effects and buttons.My problem is about showing the status bar of the device, so i thought that maybe customizing the title bar to show the notifications and the time may help.

Comment: So was this not your requirment?

Comment: Can i use the same way mentioned in the blogs to show the device time and notifications?